# Multiline Textbox allow to split wording after cursor highlight in specific word

Tags: c#, split

Let say,

I have a multiline textbox

the textbox content will be as below:

```
abc def             
ghi aa jkl         
mno pqr
```

The cursor will be located at second line after sentences 'aa'

How to use the string to split out when there is a cursor in-between 'aa'

Comment: as you see on second line, original word will be "ghi jkl". After middle of somewhere I added a text which is 'aa'. and it will split it out after I finish typing aa.

Comment: So if you put the cursor between `aa` it should split the text based on `aa`?

Comment: yes exactly based on your comment

Comment: Then edit your question with more details. Cause the current one in a bit unclear.

Comment: I suggest you use `RichTextBox` instead

Comment: "How to use the string to split out when there is a cursor in-between 'aa'"   I have no idea what that means  even after reading these comments.

Comment: Just an idea, but you could override the paint and do some fancy work to render your own highlight up to a certain index, using the font size to add up to the x width.